# MySQL query works from phpMyAdmin and returns rows, but $wpdb->get_results return nothing

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying execute a mySQL query from `$wpdb->get_results`, but nothing returns while  it works fine from phpAdmin and returns.

SQL code:

```
  $sql=" select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ref_id,
        case status
        when 0 then 'Waiting'
        when 1 then 'Invited'
        when 2 then 'Joined'
        when 3 then 'OPTOUT'
        else 'Unknow'
     end as Status,
     email,
     CONCAT(fname,' ',lname) as Name,
     ref_twitter,
     ts,
     twitter
     from ".$wpdb->base_prefix."waitingList where status!=-1 and ref_id=".$current_user->id

$invitess =$wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

`$invitess` does not return any thing.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `$wpdb` is defined. If you're doing this from within a function, make sure to declare: `global $wpdb;`

If that still doesn't work, try including `wp-load.php`.